# How to create a connection string in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

I am working on asp.net c# project, for connection I used:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

but I want to get this connection string to get configure and be like this, so can any one help how to create this kind of connection.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["itmall"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Demo :**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Based on your question:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="itmall" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

**Refer links:**

http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/

**Retrive connection string from web.config file:**

write the below code in your file where you want;

```
string connstring=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["itmall"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstring);
```

or you can go in your way like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["itmall"].ConnectionString);
```

**Note:**

The "name" which you gave in web.config file and name which you used in connection string must be same(like "itmall" in this solution.)

Answer (score 2):

```
string connectionstring="DataSource=severname;InitialCatlog=databasename;Uid=; password=;"
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(connectionstring)
```

Answer (score 2):

add this in web.config file

```
           <configuration>
              <appSettings>
                 <add key="ConnectionString" value="Your connection string which contains database id and password"/>
            </appSettings>
            </configuration>
```

.cs file

```
 public ConnectionObjects()
 {           
    string connectionstring= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="itmall" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-
02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: But what when i copy it to another folder, cant it like where we don't have to get update each time we change it's folder?

Comment: it willbe accessible from anywhere untill unless you are maintainig only one web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Add this connection string tag in web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="itmall" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And use it like you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 1):

It occurs when IIS is not being connected to SQL SERVER. For a solution, see this screenshot: [image: Solution]

Comment: can you please type out the solution? as some stack overflow users cant open pictures